# Scrapy - how to prevent output lines with blank element?

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

Using a very basic Scrapy script, I want to ensure that none of my output lines include a blank item.

That is, say I have the standard

```
    items = []
    for list in lists:
        item = TypeItem()
        item['thing1'] = list.select('h1/text()').extract()
        item['thing2'] = list.select('h2/text()').extract()
        item['thing3'] = list.select('h3/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return(items)
```

I want to prevent any csv line that says "thing1,,thing3" or ",thing2," or the like.

(I'm new to stackoverflow, so I don't know if it's appropriate to ask multiple questions at a time, but since they're related, if I could:

Q2: if I put in the check "if item not in items" before items.append(item), would it stop any duplicate full lines, or just duplicate individual items?  If the latter, how do I prevent duplicate lines?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your **Q2**, I think it would not stop duplicates because they are objects (instances of classes) and all different. You should subclass it and implement `__eq__()`.

You could achieve that goal after retrieving all elements using the `csv` parser, couldn't you?

Also, you could save the `xpath` result to a variable and check if it's blank, like:

```
thing1 = list.select('h1/text()').extract()[0]
if thing1.strip():
    ...
```

Also, you could use an additional `xpath` expression to check that none of your texts will be blank, like:

```
items = []
for list in lists:
    if list.select('.[h1[text()] and h2[text()] and h3[text()]]'):
        item = TypeItem()
        item['thing1'] = list.select('h1/text()').extract()
        item['thing2'] = list.select('h2/text()').extract()
        item['thing3'] = list.select('h3/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
return(items)
```